# API Data Not Displaying in EJS File

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, ejs

I am trying to use AJAX to get the JSON data from an API to display on my EJS file in Node JS. However, it seems that nothing is being pulled from the API in the first place. How can I display data from an API to page in Node JS? I have been trying for hours to find a solution to this one. Here is what I've got so far.

```
**index.js**

 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var url = require('url');

 app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 // views is directory for all template files
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index')
 });

 app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
 });

 var http = require("http");

 (function($) {
    $(function() {

          var status = $('#status');
          getData();

          function getData() {
            // Get the data from the Walmart API
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/trends?format=json&apiKey= 
 {api_key}",
              dataType: "jsonp",
              success: function(data) {
                //Show this data in the console
                console.log(data);
                //variable instantiation
                var itemId = data['items']['itemId'];
                var name = data['items']['name'];
                var regularPrice = data['items']['msrp'];
                var salePrice = data['items']['salePrice'];

                //Place data in HTML
                $("#productId").html(itemId);
                $("#name").html(name);
                $("#regularPrice").html(regularPrice);
                $("#salePrice").html(salePrice);
              }
            });

          }

**index.ejs**
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Store App</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
  <script type="application/json" src="/js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Store App</h1>

  <p>Welcome to the Store Node site. Here, you will find hot products on the 
Walmart website. You can also browse by category or search by product id or 
name.</p>

  <section class="item-container">
    <h1 id="name"></h1>
    <ul id="current_trends">
      <li id="productId"></li>
      <li id="regularPrice"></li>
      <li id="salePrice"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
</body>

</html>

**package.json**

 {
  "name": "node-walmart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "walmart web services",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "ejs": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sample/node-sample.git"
  },
  "author": "sample",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sample/node-sample/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sample/node-sample#readme"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use EJS like this [Node-Cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/random/small_tasks/express_server/app.js#L39)

and then you can do it like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    //see message is passed to index.ejs and ejs will take care of rendering it
    //so same way you can load your api data here like:  
    axios.get('http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/trends?format=json&apiKey={api_key}')
   .then(function (apiData) {
      //now pass apiData to index.ejs to take care of it
      res.render('index',{message:"Hello World!", apiData: apiData});
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
      //render your error.ejs here
   });
});
```

See [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) docs [here](https://github.com/axios/axios).

In case you want to use new syntax:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
        //see message is passed to index.ejs and ejs will take care of rendering it
        //so same way you can load your api data here like:  
        try {
           const apiData = axios.get('http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/trends?format=json&apiKey={api_key}');
           //now pass apiData to index.ejs to take care of it
           res.render('index',{message:"Hello World!", apiData: apiData});
        }
        catch (e){
           //render your error.ejs here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's don't work like that. You need to make the call in your API to render it on a page. IIFE don't work here as you used.